# Augmenting existing interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa

This isn't a specific koa question even though all the code is using koa, I'm just new to node and the module system.
When using Koa every request is defined by the [`Request` interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/koa/koa.d.ts#L48):

```
declare module "koa" {
    namespace Koa {
        ...

        export interface Request {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    namespace Koa {}
    export = Koa;
}
```

I'm using the bodyparser middleware so `Request` has a property named `body` but typescript is unaware of this and so I'm trying to add that by adding this definition file as a reference:

```
/// <reference path="globals/koa/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="koa.d.ts" />

import koa = require("koa");
...
app.use(ctx => {
    console.log(ctx.request.body); // error: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'
});
```

Where `koa.d.ts` is:

```
declare module "koa" {
    namespace Koa {
        export interface Request {
            body: any;
        }
    }

    export default Koa;
}
```

But this is probably the wrong way to do it as it's not working.
How can it be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to work through this. I added this to my `custom-typings.d.ts`:

```
import {Request} from "koa";

declare module "koa" {
  interface Request {
    body: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is how can I place that in a single file that I can then use so that I won't need to do this in every file in which I use koa requests?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this. I found that since I was using koa-bodyparser middleware, I needed to install the @types/koa-bodyparser module which augments the interface for you - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/koa-bodyparser/index.d.ts#L20.

```
import * as bodyparser from 'koa-bodyparser'; 
...    
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Then, in your route, "body" will be available on the request object.

```
ctx.request.body
```