# How can I use packages that extend `koa.Request` in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa

I am trying to use `koa-tree-router` and `koa-bodyparser` at the same time, but I keep getting TypeScript errors:

```js
export const userLoggingRouter = new KoaTreeRouter<any, DefaultContext>();

userLoggingRouter.post('/logs/action', (ctx) => {
  const logEntries = ctx.request.body;
  const user = ctx.state.user;

  // ...
});
```

> error TS2339: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'.

I have `@types/koa-bodyparser` installed, and it contains the following definition:

```
import * as Koa from 'koa';

declare module 'koa' {
    interface Request {
        body: string | Record<string, unknown>;
        rawBody: string;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817060/augmenting-existing-interfaces), but importing `koa-bodyparser` directly also does not do anything. How do I get TypeScript to recognize the extended `Request` type?

**Edit:** Creating a `.d.ts` file inside my project containing the following:

```js
import {Request} from "koa";

declare module "koa" {
  interface Request {
    body: any;
  }
}
```

Made the compile error go away, but this seems like an inelegant solution because I would have to copy over type information for every package that modifies `koa.Request`.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I was using Yarn PnP and I had two different versions of `@types/koa` installed. Once I added a `resolutions` field to my `package.json` that forced all of the other TypeScript definitions to use the same version of `@types/koa`, everything worked.